# Update não funcionando, mas status está ok

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, crud

Olá, estou assistindo um video sobre como fazer CRUD com ajax e acabei ficando presa na parte do UPDATE, simplesmente não está funcionando e o código aparentemente está correto.
Alguém pode me ajudar, por favor? (perdoa a identação do codKK eh urgencia)

Aqui está o formulário de Update
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aj3Fe.png

Aqui está o Ajax para requisição do code.php
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNA2m.png

e aqui está o cod para o Update

```
if(isset($_POST['update_student'])) {

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $course = $_POST['course'];
        $student_id = $_POST['student_id'];

        if($name == null || $email == null || $phone == null || $course == null) {
            $res = [
                'status' => 422,
                'message' => 'All fields are mandatory'
            ];

    
        echo json_encode($res);

        return;

        }

      

    try {

    $query =  "UPDATE students SET name='$name', email='$email', phone='$phone', course='$course' WHERE idstudents='$student_id'"; 

        $stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
        $stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
        $stmt->bindParam(":phone", $phone);
        $stmt->bindParam(":course", $course);
        $stmt->bindParam(":idstudents", $student_id);


        $stmt->execute();
        var_dump($stmt);

    $res = [
        'status' => 200,
        'message' => 'Student Updated Successfully'
    ];

    echo json_encode($res);
    return;

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    $error = [
        'status' => 500,
        'message' => 'Database Error: '. $stmt->errorInfo()[2]
    ];

    echo json_encode($error);

}
```

}

Comment: Você está fazendo bind dos parâmetros mas não está usando as variáveis no comando de UPDATE em si. Deveria estar, porque a interpolação de valores do seu código atual dá margem para ataques de injeção de SQL.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -1):

Como você fez o `bindParam`, precisa utilizá-lo no código do Update, até mesmo por questões de segurança como mencionado pelo @bfavaretto. Pode fazer algo assim:

```
$query =  "UPDATE students SET name= :name, email= :email, phone= :phone, course= :course WHERE idstudents= :idstudents"; 

$stmt = $dbc->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(":name", $name);
$stmt->bindParam(":email", $email);
$stmt->bindParam(":phone", $phone);
$stmt->bindParam(":course", $course);
$stmt->bindParam(":idstudents", $student_id);

$stmt->execute();
var_dump($stmt);
```